# KafkaConsumer generic types for avro SpecificRecord using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, apache-kafka, avro

I want to initialize `KafkaConsumer` generic types using classes loaded with reflection. The classes will be generated via `avro-tools` and will be extending `SpecificRecordBase` class. I know, I can use wildcards and do something like -

```java
KafkaConsumer<? extends SpecificRecordBase, ? extends SpecificRecordBase> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

However, I am looking for something like -

```java
Class keyClass = Class.forName("com.test.KeyClass");
Class valueClass = Class.forName("com.test.ValueClass");
KafkaConsumer<keyClass, valueClass> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is neither possible nor useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since type parameters exist only for programmers convenience, in runtime they will be erased, thus, it makes no sense to load them by reflection.

However, you can cast it to needed type, e.g.

```
Consumer<KeyClass, ValueClass> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if below suffice your requirement --

```
public Consumer<?,?> getConsumer(Class<?> keyClass,Class<?> valClass,
                                   Properties props){
    props.put(deserializer properties of keyClass);
    props.put(deserializer properties of valClass);
   //other releavant props 
   return new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
}
  ..
   caller(){
   Class<?> keyClass=Class.forName("KeyClass");
   Class<?> valClass=Class.forName("ValClass");
   KafkaConsumer<?,?> con=(KafkaConsumer<?,?>)getConsumer(keyClass,valClass,props);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup a separate task to build and publish the schema jar (I'd recommend putting them in a separate repo with it's own build). Then pull in the dependency in through Gradle/Maven, you'll have the actual types and reflection shouldn't be necessary.